# Pig: Rank start at index 0 instead of 1?

Tags: apache-pig

How would I get RANK to start at index 0 instead of 1?

```
 A = RANK A
    (1, 2)
    (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround you may use if you want . I dont think there is special RANK function that starts giving rank value from 0

Input :

```
(100,surender)
(101,raja)
(102,kumar)
```

Pig Script :

```
records = LOAD '/home/dir/records.txt' USING PigStorage(',');

records_rank = RANK records;

records_each = FOREACH records_rank GENERATE ($0-1),$1,$2;

dump records_each;
```

Output:

```
(0,100,surender)
(1,101,raja)
(2,102,kumar)
```